Issue with product variations after data migration
After a data migration of nearly 6k products from the live site. We are currently experiencing some issues with some of the products. We have contacted the plugin developers of the plugins used and they could see the issue. After they performed their necessary checks (switching themes and disabling plugins) they concluded that the issue was a generic woocommerce issue.
Edit 12/07/2024
We are using IconicWP Attribute Swatches & Product Configurator plugins. The issue arise within a variable product that uses both of the plugins. When you select a colour from the swatch it updates the product configurator image, highlights the selected colour and the text next to the option, however on some of the products this functionaility does not work.

When the functionailty does not work it writes into the browser console with following error:

After some digging in the JS, I found the code and added some debug statements
    VariationForm.prototype.isMatch = function( variation_attributes, attributes ) {
        var match = true;
        for ( var attr_name in variation_attributes ) {
            if ( variation_attributes.hasOwnProperty( attr_name ) ) {
                var val1 = variation_attributes[ attr_name ];
                var val2 = attributes[ attr_name ];

                if( val1 == null)
                {
                    console.log("Trying to find " + attr_name + " in list of variation_attributes[ attr_name ]");
                    console.log("variation_attributes below");
                    console.log(variation_attributes);
                    console.log("attributes below");
                    console.log(attributes);
                }

                if( val2 == null)
                {
                    console.log("Trying to find " + attr_name + " in list of attributes[attr_name]");
                }

                if ( val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined && val1.length !== 0 && val2.length !== 0 && val1 !== val2 ) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return match;
    };

With my debug statements I was able to see that one of the variation_attributes was null.
I've found an manual fix but it will take ages to complete this task manually. After the fix the frontend is working as expected.

So I looked on SO to find if anybody has the same or smiliar issue and found this post : Woocommerce: function to update all products the fix didn't work.
Below is my code from my functions.php. I've added some debug statements to see how long the process takes to process 200 products

 if (!function_exists('write_log'))
 {
    function write_log($log)
    {
        if (true === WP_DEBUG)
        {
            if (is_array($log) || is_object($log))
            {
                error_log(print_r($log, true));
            }
            else
            {
                error_log($log);
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'update_products_by_x' );


function update_products_by_x()
{
    $limit = 200;

    // getting all products
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        =>  ['product','product_variation'],
        'numberposts'      => $limit,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
           'key'     => '_sync_updated',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ) )
    ) );

    if( count($products_ids) > 0 )
    {
        $randomId = wp_rand();
        $current_date_time_start = current_datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log_products_message_start = $randomId . " | " . $current_date_time_start . " | function: update_products_by_x | Start";
        write_log($log_products_message_start);
        write_log($products_ids);

        // Loop through product Ids
        foreach ( $products_ids as $product_id ) {

            // Get the WC_Product object
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

            // Mark product as updated
            $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', true );

            $product->save();
        }

        $current_date_time_end = current_datetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log_products_message_end = $randomId . " | " . $current_date_time_end . " | function: update_products_by_x | End ";
        write_log($log_products_message_end);
    }
    else
    {
        write_log("update_products_by_x has no products to process");
    }
}

Manual Fix
Within the variations tab I unticked "Enabled" on all the variations, then pressed the saved changes. Then I clicked the update button.
I then checked the frontend for the product and the product was now “out of stock” and did not display any of the options.
Went back into the variations and the ticked "Enabled" on all the variations then pressed the saved changes and press the update.
Checked the product again and now all the options are back and when selected they update the selected text.
The client was trying this fix but they were using the “Bulk Actions” and “toggle ‘Enabled’” instead of going into each individual and amended “Enabled” tick box but that didn’t fix the issue. So doing the individual changes saves all the variation attributes and this somehow resolves the issue.
Please can someone help in converting the manual process into a automated process.

Your question is too vague, and nobody can guess things by magic. You say "We are currently experiencing some issues with some of the products", What is the issue that you are "experiencing" with some of those products? What do the products you are facing an issue with, have in common? Are they only product variations, for example? Try to be more explicit, clarifying your question by editing it.

@LoicTheAztec, I've updated my question with more information

This seems more like a bug related to IconicWP Attribute Swatches or Product Configurator plugin. So you should report this bug to the related plugin support.
